# A really weird issue about UITextField

Tags: uitextfield, null

I have a textField here, and I tap it so it become the first responder,

then I leave it **without inputting anything**, which i think means the textField.text remains nil.

And its delegate will go to this method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    if (textField.text == nil)
        return YES;
    ...

}
```

and it just does not execute the return inside the IF!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'isEqualToString:'

Try this

```
if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@""])
```

Or just check the length

```
if ([textField.text length] == 0)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works well! So would you mind telling me what's wrong with my method that == nil? Thank you!

Comment: The == operator compares pointers. You want to compare the values of the strings instead